# Weasyprint output format issue - how to use CSS @page?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, weasyprint

I used to use wkhmtltopdf to print some webpages but unfortunately it doesn't work anymore with some modern websites.

I found weasyprint which I tried in command line. The output has all the contents but text is cropped probably due to page size.
The website tells this is customizable in CSS (https://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#adjusting-document-dimensions). I'm not a web expert and don't really know what to do here. Should I copy and edit the source code of the webpage ? Where should it be inserted then ?

Here is sample webpage I'd like to print properly as a pdf:
https://korben.info/8-clients-alternatifs-pour-spotify.html

Has anyone succeeded in proper printing with weasyprint ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

**Adjusting Document Dimensions**

Currently, WeasyPrint does not provide support for adjusting page size or document margins via command-line flags. This is best accomplished with the CSS @page at-rule. Consider the following example:

```
@page {
  size: Letter; /* Change from the default size of A4 */
  margin: 2.5cm; /* Set margin on each page */
}
```

@page is a CSS media query, so you have to write down the code in a .css file.
Once  done you can call

> weasyprint -s path/to/css/file input output

Notice that complex pages are usually bad rendered by weasyprint, as there are few not-supported style tags (calc, var, overflow on precise axis, ecc..).
Let me say that working like taht is a mess, if you need to do complex things consider to use weasyprint as a Python lib and not in standalone mode, so you can process sources and achieve better results in whatever you need to do.

Hope it helps.
Hele.